# Luxury Numbers Table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Numbers tables are truly invaluable and useful in variety situations.
There are many ways of creating and populating a numbers table in sql.
What is the best, most optimal way of dealing with this in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few reasonable options I found applicable in most cases within GBQ.
My favorite so far is not to use any existing table(s) as a basis, but rather generate it on fly and use in-line with main sql logic

```
SELECT pos 
FROM (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos, h 
     FROM (FLATTEN((
        SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', :VAR_END, '.'),'') AS h FROM (SELECT NULL)),h
))) 
WHERE pos BETWEEN :VAR_START AND :VAR_END
AND (pos - :VAR_START) % :VAR_STEP = 0
```

Replace   **:VAR_START, :VAR_STEP and :VAR_END** with Values you need and you get respective Numbers Table on fly

This approach works in most cases for me and easily transforms for other cases.
For example, Dates Table:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(:VAR_START), pos - 1, "DAY")) as day
FROM (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos, h
     FROM (FLATTEN((
         SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', 1 + DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP(:VAR_END), TIMESTAMP(:VAR_START)), '.'),'') AS h
         FROM (SELECT NULL)),h
)))
```

Replace **:VAR_START and :VAR_END** with respectively '2015-08-25' and '2015-09-15' and you have all days in that table

Another option I use sometimes is JS UDF to generate more advanced sequences